# How dynamically imports images from my assets folder?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, electron, electron-forge

I've follow this [tutorial](https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react-with-typescript) to get the boiler plate code for my project.

The problem: my program is some kind of gallery of images that reads a folder to get the assets, so i don't have acces to the name of the files and i can't make a static import and the dynamic import did'nt find the assets.

My code:

```
import React from "react";


interface Props {
    mock?: false;
    src: string;
    title: string;
    compiler: string;
}

interface MockProps {
    mock: true;
    [x: string]: any;
}

const mockProps: Props = {
    mock: false,
    src: "../../public/assets/images/asd.png",
    title: "./",
    compiler: "",
};

export default function AlbumCard(props: Props | MockProps): JSX.Element {

    const { mock } = props;
    const realProps = mock ? mockProps : props;

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <img src={realProps.src} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My webpack file:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules:[ {
        test: /\.node$/,
        use: "node-loader",
    },
    {
        test: /\.(m?js|node)$/,
        parser: { amd: false },
        use: {
            loader: "@marshallofsound/webpack-asset-relocator-loader",
            options: {
                outputAssetBase: "native_modules",
            },
        },
    },
    {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|\.webpack)/,
        use: {
            loader: "ts-loader",
            options: {
                transpileOnly: true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|jp2|webp)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]",
        },
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [{ loader: "style-loader" }, { loader: "css-loader" }],
    }]

    },
    plugins: plugins,
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".css", ".png"]
    },
};
```

What i get:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

What am I missing here?